# Linked list leaks?

Tags: c++, list

I am not too versed in C++, but I had the task of designing and implementing a linked list. This is what I handed in:

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    Node() : next(nullptr) {}
    Node(T const & val) : next(nullptr), value(val) {}

    Node * next;
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
    public:
        LinkedList()
        {
            begin_ = new Node<T>;
            current_ = begin_;
        }
        ~LinkedList()
        {
            delete begin_;
        }

        void insert(T const & value)
        {
            Node<T> * node = new Node<T>(value);
            node->next = current_->next;
            current_->next = node;
            current_ = current_->next;
        }

        void remove()
        {
            Node<T> * tmp = current_->next;
            if(!end())
            {
                current_->next = current_->next->next;
            }
            delete tmp;
        }

        bool end() const
        {
            return current_->next == nullptr;
        }

        void reset()
        {
            current_ = begin_;
        }

        void advance()
        {
            if(!end())
            {
                current_ = current_->next;
            }
        }

        T get() const
        {
            return current_->next->value;
        }

    private:
        Node<T> * begin_;
        Node<T> * current_;
};
```

I passed the assignment, but my teacher underlined the `delete begin_` in the destructor `~LinkedList()` and wrote "This leaks!" next to it. I have been thinking about how `delete begin_` could possibly leak but I still do not understand. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Oh, Your teacher probably missed saying that you did not follow [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @Als What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go through every node in the list and delete.  Hold a separate pointer to next, delete current, then move forward and continue deleting until next pointer is null.

```
~LinkedList()
{
    Node * current = begin_;
    Node * aNext = begin_->next;

    while (null != aNext){
        delete(current);
        current = aNext;
        aNext = current->next;
    }
}
```

Something like this.  Don't know where you're getting begin_ from, but........

Comment: Oh, I've been completely stuck on the line he underlined, that I didn't even think of the possibility he could be talking about the other nodes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: NO problem whatsoever :-) glad to help.  Also, might think to "accept" your best answer, this will help you later also when you have more questions.

Comment: Yes, of course; it would not let me accept an answer for a certain amount of minutes though!

Answer (score 0):

In the destructor of Node it should send the delete command to `next` so that it frees up all nodes in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will understand it better this way:

```
~LinkedList()
{
  reset();
  while(!end()) remove();
}
```